# android позиция recyclerview при прокрутке изменяется

Tags: android, recyclerview, position

есть проблема с recyclerview
есть recyclerview  в котором есть названия тестов и есть массив выполненных  тестов рядом с recyclerview  отображается оценка за тест поиск оценки идет в адаптере в методе onBindViewHolder

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(furnitureView: FurnitureView, position: Int) {   if (idComplite != null) {
        for (j in idComplite!!.indices) {
            if (position == idComplite!![j] ) {
                furnitureView.scores.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                furnitureView.scores.text = "score:" + scoresRes[j] + "%"
                //  furnitureView.imgScore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
```

есть проблема когда список большой и прокручиваем вниз  scores в списке начинает показываться не в тех местах .
заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему у вас стандартная ошибка - в RecyclerView вьюхи переиспользуются, засим надо не забывать совершать обратные операции при изменении оных. Т.е., если вы по к-л условию делаете что-то видимым - то надо при несовпадении условия делать это невидимым.

В вашем случае - добавьте else и там скройте вьюху:

```
if (position == idComplite!![j] ) {
    furnitureView.scores.visibility = View.VISIBLE
} else {
    furnitureView.scores.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Comment: добавить else я пробовал он тогда показывает score только на одном элементе который был последний пройденный а должно быть на всех пройденных  score я думаю это как то связано  с экономией памяти в recyclerview и по идеи это можно как то отключить

Comment: @dimasta68, видимо что-то не то в логике. Попробуйте, например, завершать цикл после включения видимости вьюхе. Вроде бы можно это через return сделать